# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for paypal using MVC

Tags: c#, ssl, paypal

I am getting error `could not create ssl/tls secure channel` even I have added all the security mechanism as suggested in all other questions and blogs.

Here is the code.

```
public static PDTHolder Success(string tx)
{
    authToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalToken"];
    txToken = tx;
    query = string.Format("cmd=_notify-synch&tx={0}&at={1}", txToken, authToken);
    string url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AllwaysGoodCertificate);
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = query.Length;

    StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    stOut.Write(query);
    stOut.Close();
}

private static bool AllwaysGoodCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
     return true;
}
```

Can anybody please suggest?